# Android error: cannot find symbol class ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, compiler-errors

I am currently Using Android Studio (Beta) 0.8.6 and when I try to run an app into my device, the following error appears:

```
 error: cannot find symbol class ActionBarActivity
```

I looked up for the solution for this error and found the following:
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24382959/cannot-find-symbol-actionbaractivity-following-android-development-tutorial)

Unfortunately I am not under Eclipse.

The code I try to run is the following:

```
package com.example.doblevxv5.sunny;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

/**
 * Created by Doble Vx V5 on 8/11/14.
 */
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new ForecastFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

I am running with API 17. Android 4.1.2
Do you have any suggestion guys?

Thanks!

Comment: This is because the class couldn't find ActionBarActivity class. The mistake you have done is you didn't import ActionBarActivity. Here you go `import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;` For this you need to import appCompat_v7 to your workspace! If you are a beginner i would encourage you to start working on with Eclipse.

Comment: I wish I could use another IDE. Unfortunately I have to use Android Studio for this course I am taking. I already imported but here is what the log says: Error:(6, 30) error: package android.support.v7.app does not exist

Comment: Go to your build.gradle and add ` compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'` and build your gradle and give that import statement.

Comment: When I try to import that into the build.gradle the following mesagge appears: Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.

Comment: I think you missing out lot of basic things. I encourage you to learn and know about Android Studio IDE first. You need to set your project to 5.0 and i hope u downloaded latest api's. Open SDK manager and install or update latest api specially tools category.

Answer (score 57):

`ActionBarActivity` was deprecated below API level 25. Instead use `AppCompatActivity`

Comment: Thanks Aaron, this solved it for me! Had to switch out a few locations where the old import was used.

Answer (score 2):

In your `build.gradle` add following line under `dependencies` block:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'
```

Also make sure to have **compileSdkVersion** and **targetSdkVersion** set to **21** under `android` block.

Then Sync your project. If `autoimport` is disabled - add this import:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
```

Also update Android Studio and gradle plugin to the latest version.

Comment: Already did it and this is the first line the log shows:

Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.

Comment: Not suitable for android studio 3.0.1

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following import to your activity:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
```

for this to work you require the support library. Take a look at this
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316055/actionbaractivity-cannot-resolve-a-symbol)

Comment: Just added it and it shows the following: Error:(6, 30) error: package android.support.v7.app does not exist

I did take a look before to that link and still does not work.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you downloaded the support package? here is another link that might help https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Answer (score 0):

have you included the android.support.v7.app library in your project?. You need this library in order to use the Action bar.

Please refer to this link.
[enter link description here](http://gmariotti.blogspot.com/2013/07/how-to-add-actionbarcompat-to-your.html)

Comment: I just did it and it shows: Error:(6, 26) error: package android.support.v7 does not exist

Answer (score 0):

`ActionBarActivity` is not standard component of Android. You need to use support lib ([docs](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html)) to have this class available ([docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html))

> Base class for activities that use the support library action bar
>   features.

Answer (score 0):

Where you have

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
```

you need to replace by

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
```

you also need to change the import from

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
```

to

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

and finally, you need to add the dependency to the `build.gradle` file

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:xxx.0.+'
```

where xxx is the `compileSdkVersion` version of your App., up to 28.